# What statement equivalent for DEFINE statement of Oracle in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server

I want to declare the below statement of Oracle in SQL Server:

```
DEFINE SYNTEMPO_USER_NAME=&SYNTEMPO_USER_NAME
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare @myVar varchar(100); -- or nvarchar, etc.
Set @myVar = 'literal';

Select @myVar = mycolumn
   from mytable
     where mytable.tableid = 1;
```